# How to manually scale desktop applications in Kubernetes on-demand

Tags: kubernetes, vnc, xserver

I have a containerized legacy application using **VNC** as an **XServer**.
I'd like to run this application in a **Kubernetes** cluster, and start an application instance on-demand, when a new user logs in the system.

I'd like to

- scale the number of PODs on-demand and not automatically with the *replicas* property
- provide unique host/port to the clients to connect to their own VNC server?

How can I achieve this in K8S?

Comment: Do you have the computing resources available for all users or would you be looking to spin up virtual machines etc. as more users log in and start up instances?

Comment: Suppose, we have large enough computing resource available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a bit contradictory, since on-demand scaling is a variant of automatic scaling.
Given your constraints you could create a custom application in which users request their connection data. Upon request your application talks to the kubernetes api and scales up the number of instances.

You would use a headless service to get the list of endpoints and associate a specific endpoint to a user. Your application would reserve a specific port for that user. You then have to create a new nodeport or loadbalancer service to expose this port of your application that forwards to the chosen instance.

After all this sounds like a lot of effort, perhaps your concept is not a good match for kubernetes.

Comment: Thanks Thomas! Yes, you are right, this is a kind of on-demand scaling. I had something similar in my mind. I wanted to call the K8S API to create a POD for each user, but I am not sure it is a proper use of the API. Is it ok to create dynamically the headless services for each user? Or you mean, I should update a singe service every time a new POD is started?

Comment: Headless service allows you to retrieve all instances of a service via endpoints, they are automatically updated. Discussing the details and trade-offs of all possible variants is out of scope for a SO question from my point of view, I wanted to provide you with the general building block you can use to approach your scenario.